# Ansible installed from tar. No module named ansible.runner error

Tags: python, module, ansible, python-2.4

Having trouble launching ansible after untarring it from a tapped archive, downloaded from the source. It seems that the module is present, but for whatever reason ansible can't import it. Are there additional steps that you have to execute for this to work?

```
[mybox1 bin]$./ansible --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ansible", line 36, in ?
    from ansible.runner import Runner
ImportError: No module named ansible.runner
```

Current configuration:

- 2.6.18-402.el5
- ansible-1.9.2
- Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you might have just unpacked the tar and executed `bin/ansible`. You have to install it. The installation instructions can be found in the [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source):

```
cd ./ansible
sudo make install
```

Comment: I am running into another error. I also haven't mentioned that the box has no connectivity to outer world. I was only able to push ansible.tar. When I am running 
make install I get the following error
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
python setup.py install
Ansible now needs setuptools in order to build. Install it using your package manager (usually python-setuptools) or via pip (pip install setuptools).
make: *** [install] Error 1
and these packages are installed setuptools  python-setuptools